# Django relational database in view

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a django application where I have few manytomany fields and im trying to show these relation records in my listing, however it all comes blank

so this is my model:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    genre_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genre_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    genre_meta = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    genre_description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    listing = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.genre_name

class Movie(models.Model):
    movie_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    movie_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    movie_description = models.TextField(null=True, max_length=300)
    movie_category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='category')
    movie_genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, blank=True, related_name='genre')
    listing = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.movie_name
```

this is my view

```
def AllMovies (request):
    movies= Movie.objects.all().order_by('movie_name')
    context = {'movies': movies}
    return render_to_response('all.html', context, context_instance=
RequestContext(request))
```

and this is my template

```
 {% for movie in movies %}
<a href="/movies/{{ movie.movie_slug }}/">{{ movie }}</a>
{% for genre in movies.genre.all %}{{ genre_name }}{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

so there are three concerns here:

1- All I get is blank in my template

2- What would be the best option to show items which have been ticked as listed and hide the rest in template

3- This is a data bank so im sure we will need to use load more button in my template, but if i want to show 30 of items instead of all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for movie in movies %}
    <a href="/movies/{{ movie.movie_slug }}/">{{ movie }}</a>
    {% for genre in movie.movie_genre.all %}{{ genre_name }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You were trying to iterate over `movies.genre.all`, which is wrong because:

- `movies` is a queryset, you should use `movie` instead, as it is a Model instance
- `genre` is not a field in the Movie model, you should use `movie_genre`, which is a ManyToManyField you are looking for

I believe you didn't understand the `related_name` attribute. It doesn't modify the behavior of the field (in this case: `movie_genre`). Instead, it changes the name of an attribute in a related model (in this case: `Genre`). For example, you can use it to get all related movies:

```
>>> genre = Genre.objects.get(name='Drama')
>>> genre.genre.all()
[<Movie>, <Movie>, ...]
```

As you can see, your choice of a `related_name` wasn't so good. Something like `movies` would be more appropriate.

Please, read the documentation once again, as you probably didn't understand Django's logic around relations (foreign keys, many-to-many, etc.).

Besides, here are a few style-related tips:

- don't use `movie_` and `genre_` prefixes in field names - e.g. it is obvious that `genre_name` is a name of a genre, since it is defined inside `Genre` model
- try to follow PEP8 (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), as it is a standard in the Python community
- read about class-based views (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) - you may find them very helpful

Comment: I was in the middle of typing an answer but @piotrekw has explained it well. Regarding @user3482036 second question, you can use [the `if` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if) to conditionally show listed movies/genres. Regarding the third question, you can [paginate your results](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/)

Comment: Thank you both for great advises, im a noob when it comes to django but getting there :) - in regards to your answer, it still doesnt show anything.

Comment: Ok this is working now and this is how i have resolved it

    {% for movie in movies %}
    <a href="/movies/{{ movie.movie_slug }}/">{{ movie }}</a>
    {% for genre in movie.movie_genre.all %}{{ genre_name }}{% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}


Thank you all

Comment: Indeed. However filtering the queryset by `listing=True` would be more efficient. This way or another, using generic ListView class (which is class-based view) would make the code even simpler, as it provides pagination by default.